# Comparison with fmod() result returning false

Tags: c++, floating-point, modulus

I'm having a problem with the `fmod()` function.

This code should be true, but somehow it's not. Any help?

```
if (fmod(1.9, 0.3) == 0.1) {  
    cout << "True." << endl;  
}
```

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic is inexact.

Comment: I would suggest you to refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) before trying anything.

Comment: ...not exact... as would be shown by doing cout<<fmod(1.9,0.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point number aren't exact. One way you could do this is,

```
#include <limits>

if (fabs(fmod(1.9,0.3) - 0.1) <  std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()) {
    cout << "True." << endl;
}
```

However, this is a crude solution that isn't entirely correct. Do a few searches for how to compare doubles/floats on stackoverflow for some discussions on the issue.